# Why do so many Android games ask for full file access instead of using Internal Storage?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Many major games start out by asking for full file read permissions:  `Allow APPNAME to access photos, media, and files on your device`

I'm assuming that is android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

This seems dangerous to grant arbitrary apps to read any files on your phone.  Why wouldn't the games use [Internal Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html)?

I'm not the only one with this question, there are unanswered posts [like this](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/846271-allow-game-access-photos-media-files-your-device.html) with the same concern.  An [example game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apxsoft.s1945ww&hl=en) that request it.

Comment: I guess some years ago internal storage was way smaller, up to hundreds of mb. Also, external storage, such as sd cards were more prevalent. Users needed to have a chance to transfer some of app's data to external storage to not run out of internal one.

Nowadays this does not seem to be a problem due to large storage. Maybe some frameworks like unity implement this permission by default?

Comment: Internal storage also used to have a per-app limit, which changed by manufacturer but was frequently about 40 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s actually recommended in the Android docs:

> If you are handling files that are not intended for other apps to use
>   (such as graphic textures or sound effects used by only your app), you
>   should use a private storage directory on the external storage by
>   calling getExternalFilesDir()

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal